# vue cli3 enable CORS

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have had this problem for nearly 2 days, any help would be a life saver.

I have my vue app running on 8080 dev mode and I am trying to integrate blockstack login and that app tries to read http://localhost/manifest.json, so I placed it in static directory, but it is throwing me cors error, do we have solution for that vue cli configurations like vue.config.js?

Comment: CORS issues need to be resolved as part of your server configuration. Which port is your server running on on Localhost? Or are you literally trying to access a local file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "correct answer" doesn't actually help in this instance.

Blockstack needs to be able to hit the `manifest.json` file (in this case `localhost:8080/manifest.json`). When the server doesn't support CORS Blockstack will throw an error.

What the OP is asking is how to make "vue-cli-service serve" allow COR requests to happen. To do this, we need to modify Webpack's dev server to allow the CORS request.

Add `vue.config.js` (if it doesn't already exist)

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That was interesting, what i didn't realize was that not only the server serving the page the request is coming from has to allow CORS, but also the server the request is going to... That cost me a minute to figure out ;p

Comment: This works. Someone give this beautiful man a beer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you are having. I applied what the documentation of vue-js says to put some code in vue.config.js like this

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
  }
}
```

but that would'nt help. See this documentation https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver .
I have separate backend which is in laravel,What i did after having wasting too much time in allowing cors in vue-js, i applied cors on my backend index.php file and that worked like a charm.
The problem is you don't really know where is it coming from but look at both front end and  backend side and then try to find solution on both sides.

Comment: The tip to see backend cors configuration was the key to resolve my problem... Great answer !!!